# Flutter Connected Node/Graph of Widgets

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

What would be the best approach to get started on creating something like this:

[image: flutter-graph-layout]

I could probably get the second & fourth rows created as horizontally scrolled lists, with the first & third rows as just a row with two cards; but how does one draw a line between or connecting two widgets?

Comment: did you find a solution? I would use custom painter and draw the graph... But I dont know this is a good solution. I would be nice if somebody can make an example with panning and zooming

Comment: This can be done manually with a Stack Widget, a CustomPainter and canvas. But it wouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic? I found this library: https://github.com/Team-Blox/GraphView but this is only for android and not for flutter

Comment: @wwwwwwwwwwww, I'm guessing dynamic here would be passing the number of nodes at each level at runtime to create the graph on the fly with possibly different data on each run. I haven't found a solution yet, but the answer below looks promising (also looks like a lot of work).

Answer (score 5):

The only way i could think of creating such a view is a little complicated (may be iam wrong)Please enlighten me if someone know any packages or simple widgets or some other way to do it .

The core feature of flutter is reusability of code but sadly until now no one has created a GraphView the way i think of doing this is ... Iam not going to implement it here I'll certainly wouldve give it a try soon.
Although I will Share the way i think of implementing it and the steps required to do so.

> 1) You have to build a container or any widget to hold whatever data
>   there is in the node.
>
> 2) You have to find the coordinates of each of this nodes using a
>   function say getOffset(). To do this I found a good youtube tutorial
>   [Video to find position and size of a widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uMLR7D4npE). Its actually quite
>   simple(after i saw the tutorial) you have to create a key for each
>   node and pass it as the key parameter to the node widget and use the
>   initstate funtion to create a function which uses the `_newBox =
>   _theKeyYouCreated.currentContext.findRenderObject()` to find that object
>
> 3) Then use `_newBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero)` to get the location
>   of the object.
>
> 4)Now say you got all the location of the containers now just use this
>   locations to draw some line between these container.If you want some
>   more beautiful right angled straight line you can first go to through
>   the y axis then draw the x axis(of course some extra distance to
>   compensate for the width and heights of widgets is to be used)
>
> 5)Drawing lines between two co-ordinates is a pretty straight forward
>   thing with
>
> ```
> canvas.drawLine(p1, p2, paint);
> ```
>
> 6)Now if you manage to do this for all pairs of nodes You are done.

Seems like a pretty lot of work.I think there are no packages that do this .But its certainly Time to make one. If you manage to to do this just make it in a reusable form and publish it .I'll certainly give a try to implement this after my current project.

Comment: the nodes are normal flutter widget containers? What about zoom and pan? Can I do this with GestetureDetector?

Comment: wrap the entire thing with a zoomable widget like zoom widget from https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget